# Onclick of Checkbox,place the checked value into a textbox and delete the unchecked value from textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, checkbox

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <html>
      <head>
     <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpryvkin/Plugins/master/pagination/simple_numbers_no_ellipses.js"></script>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

      </head>
      <body>

    <div>
    <form action="/home/divya/html_docs/click.html" method="post" id="form1">
    Client_ip :<input type="text" id ="ip" name="client_ip" style="width: 600px;"/>
    <div id="subDiv">
    <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </div></br>

    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    </table>

     <script>

      $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#ip").val('');

        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        } );
    } );


      var tabulate = function (data,columns) {
    var svg = d3.select('#ip').append("svg")
      var table = d3.select('#example')
        var thead = table.append('thead')
        var tbody = table.append('tbody')

        thead.append('tr')
          .selectAll('th')
            .data(columns)
            .enter()
          .append('th')
            .text(function (d) { return d })

        var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
          .append('tr')

        var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
            .data(function(row) {
                return columns.map(function (column) {
                    return { column: column, value: row[column] }
              })
          })
          .enter()
        .append('td')
       .text(function (d) { return d.value })
       .append("input")
       .attr("id","change")
       .attr("type", "checkbox")
       .style("float","left")


    .on("click", function(d,i) { 

            var csv = $(':checkbox[id=change]:checked').map(function(){return this.value;}).get().join(',');

            $('#ip').val(csv);

    });

      return table;
    }


    d3.csv('http://localhost:3000/getcsv',function (data) {
        var columns = ['client_ip']
      tabulate(data,columns)
    });
      </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here,

```
 .on("click", function(d,i) { 

                    var csv = $(':checkbox[id=change]:checked').map(function(){return this.value;}).get().join(',');

                    $('#ip').val(csv);

            });
```

In this part,instead of getting "client_ip" in the csv variable,I'm getting "on" as the csv variable.

When we select a checkbox,how to get all the client_ip's in a text box instead of "on" value.When we deselect a checkbox,how to delete the deseclected value from the textbox.

Can any anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Comment: there is no checkbox in your question is your title the correct title?

Comment: ya I had appended Checkbox here,                                                     var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
            .data(function(row) {
                return columns.map(function (column) {
                    return { column: column, value: row[column] }
              })
          })
          .enter()
        .append('td')
       .text(function (d) { return d.value })
       .append("input")
       .attr("id","change")
       .attr("type", "checkbox")
       .style("float","left")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In map function you return the checkbox value instead of returning the text in the cell.

Change map Function

```
var csv = $(':checkbox[id=change]:checked').map(function(){return this.value;})
```

to this

```
var csv = $(':checkbox[id=change]:checked').map(function(){return $(this).parent().text();})
```